React Vite Project on Hostinger Showing "Failed to Load Module Script" Error
I am hosting a React Vite project on Hostinger and using GitHub for version control. My repository is structured with two main folders: frontend (where my React project resides) and backend. By default, Hostinger serves files from the public_html directory, but I needed to serve the files from the frontend folder instead.
To achieve this, I created an .htaccess file inside public_html with the following content:
# Redirect to frontend folder
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wactechx.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.wactechx.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !frontend/
RewriteRule (.*) /frontend/$1 [L]

This allows me to reach my React project when accessing my domain. However, nothing renders on the webpage except the page title. When I check the console, I encounter this error:
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
Here is my main.jsx file:
import { StrictMode } from 'react'
import { createRoot } from 'react-dom/client'
import './index.css'
import App from './App.jsx'

createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>,
)

I suspect this is a MIME type issue, but I am unsure how to resolve it. I would appreciate any insights or solutions to ensure my React app loads correctly.
I tried redirecting to the frontend folder by modifying the .htaccess file to ensure Hostinger serves files from there instead of public_html. I expected the React Vite project to load properly when accessing the domain. However, the page only shows the title, and the console returns a MIME type error, preventing the app from rendering.
